# Edit y-axis according to registered values

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

Hi I have a list of dataframes, with data like this:

Element 1 subset to year 2018

```
    structure(list(year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"), month = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), Avdischarge = c(906.5947917, 
511.2469444, 364.0697222, 268.3026389, 141.5931944, 142.0445486, 
37.53111111, 34.68916667, 35.50809028, 26.94083333, 40.400381945, 
312.0436806), IndustrialCompound = c(0.729166666666667, 0.815789473684211, 
0.818181818181818, 0.771428571428571, 0.736842105263158, 0.761904761904762, 
0.780487804878049, 0.829268292682927, 0.8, 0.780487804878049, 
0.738095238095238, 0.731707317073171), Pharmaceutical = c(0.145833333333333, 
0.105263157894737, 0.113636363636364, 0.142857142857143, 0.131578947368421, 
0.119047619047619, 0.121951219512195, 0.0975609756097561, 0.114285714285714, 
0.146341463414634, 0.166666666666667, 0.195121951219512), Pesticide = c(0.125, 
0.0789473684210526, 0.0681818181818182, 0.0857142857142857, 0.131578947368421, 
0.119047619047619, 0.0975609756097561, 0.0731707317073171, 0.0857142857142857, 
0.0731707317073171, 0.0952380952380952, 0.0731707317073171), 
    TotalOvershootings = c(0.48, 0.558823529411765, 0.619718309859155, 
    0.538461538461538, 0.612903225806452, 0.591549295774648, 
    0.561643835616438, 0.554054054054054, 0.538461538461538, 
    0.577464788732394, 0.617647058823529, 0.694915254237288)), row.names = 37:48, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot the discharge, so I used

```
a <- ggplot(subset(counts[["HEE"]], year==2018), aes(x=month)) +
      geom_line(aes(y= Avdischarge, group=1), color='royalblue1', size=1.5, alpha=0.8) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks= counts[["HEE"]][["month"]])+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = counts[["HEE"]][["Avdischarge"]])
```

and I obtained this

[image: example]

1.Why is my y-axis showing more values? I just want the 12 values of discharge. Probably is because of the subset and is also showing the discharge of the other years?  How can I set it only for 2018?

2. How can I make the distance between the ticks equal?

Basically I want to get something like this (just the blue line)

[image: discharge]

Only the registered values of discharge are on the y-axis, and the distance between them in the plot is the same. 
I did this some months ago and even use the same code and without the scale_y_continuous and I got that result. I don't know why it doesn't plot like that anymore.

Comment: use `scale_y_discrete` maybe? Here for more info: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-scales-and-transformations#use-scale_xx-functions

Comment: When I use discrete my y-axis disappears

Comment: Probably because you feed a subset (2018) of your data to `ggplot()` and use the non-subsetted data to set the breaks of the y-axis. If you want to plot a subset of your data, it would probably be best to subset the data.frame before plotting.

Comment: I try subsetting first and now it shows tha values I want, but I don't get the same distance between ticks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in your `breaks` argument. This works for me:

```
ggplot(subset(dta, year==2018), aes(x=month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= Avdischarge, group=1), color='royalblue1', size=1.5, alpha=0.8) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 1000, by=50))
```

I'm not sure what your `counts[["HEE"]][["Avdischarge"]]`, but you just need to specify the actual values you want to show (eg `20, 70, 120, ...`)

Comment: counts[["HEE"]][["Avdischarge"]] is referencing the column Avdischarge, the values I want to show exactly

Comment: well thats exactly whats showing then. try just looking at `sort(counts[["HEE"]][["Avdischarge"]])` and you'll see all the same numbers as showing in your plot. If you want the same distance between the ticks, then you need to specify numbers equally spaced apart

Comment: in response to your other comment, if you don't specify `scale_y_continuous` ggplot will use some formula to generate appropriate, equally spaced values for the graph. `scale_y_continuous` overrides that and forces ggplot to use your exact values, no matter how poorly spaced they are